# How to transclude div's content as a table header?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have made a custom directive for a table in Angular JS which represents like this

```
   `<div mytable api="data">
        <div col="A"></div>
        <div col="B"></div>
    </levelOne>`
```

myTable directive has a templateUrl associated with it which has table and paging options. right now i have hard code the column names. But i want my column names col=A and col=B inside the parent directive mytable. Problem is that mytable is replaced by the templateUrl and i cannot get the inside elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand what are you trying to achieve with that but would like to provide a solution which you can build up on.

Declare your directives (note the hyphenated element names):

```
<div mytable api="data">
    <div col="ID"></div>
    <div col="NAME"></div>
</div>
```

Now define the directive `mytable` as:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.data = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'One'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Two'
    }];
});
myApp.directive('mytable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        template: 
            '<table>\
                <thead></thead>\
                <tbody>\
                    <tr ng-repeat="d in data">\
                        <td ng-bind="d.id"></td>\
                        <td ng-bind="d.name"></td>\
                    </tr>\
                </tbody>\
            </table>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.data = $scope.$eval($attrs.api);
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, NullController, $transcludeFn) {
            $transcludeFn(function(tElement) {
                var headHTML = '<tr>';
                for (var i = 0; i < tElement.length; i++) {
                    if (tElement[i].nodeType === 1) {
                        headHTML+= '<td>' + angular.element(tElement[i]).attr('col') + '</td>';
                    }
                }
                headHTML+= '</tr>';
                element.find('thead').html(headHTML);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

New Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/aa18tuzf/

Old Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/yy4rc49L/

Comment: Thanks alot but i am using templateUrl for parent directive

Comment: What i am trying to do is to make a templateUrl for a table and it wil be like levelOne and inside levelOne i will give levelTwo tag which are basically columns name so that i can get columns names first than wil use columns in levelOne for the table which i made in html template

Comment: so how would you basically use those directives in HTML? What the template will be like for both the directives?

Comment: In HTML i used like this 
    '<div mytable apiurl="data">
       <div col="A"></div>
        <div col="B"></div>
      </div>'

Comment: @ZeeshanSaleem: I think you better update your question to add more clarify.